# Rails 4, Devise & Omniauth - no method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to make an app with Rails 4  & devise.

I am trying to follow this tutorial:

http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/

When I complete the steps, and run the server, I get this error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass):
2015-12-14T20:37:03.180526+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:43:in `finish_signup'
2015-12-14T20:37:03.180540+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

the finish sign up method is:

```
 def finish_signup
    # authorize! :update, @user 
    if request.patch? && params[:user] #&& params[:user][:email]
      if @user.update(user_params)
        @user.skip_reconfirmation!
        sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
        redirect_to @user, notice: 'Your profile was successfully updated.'
      else
        @show_errors = true
      end
    end
  end
```

The specific line identified as the problem is:

```
  if @user.update(user_params)
```

Does anyone see what's going wrong? I don't know how to read the error to understand what it's complaining about. Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: You don't initialize @user variable.

Comment: Hi, i"m really  sorry, but not sure what you mean. Do you mean I should write @current_user instead?

Comment: Do you have `before_action :set_filter`, like in example? You should, otherwise there's no `@user` instance variable set.

Comment: Yes before_action :set_user, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

Comment: I should add :finish_signup, right?

Comment: Yes, you should add this action.

Comment: @user2860931, you should do something like this: '@user = User.new(params[:user])'  and only then run '@user.update' method

Comment: Thans a lot - that worked. I've been trying for weeks to figure that out. Thanks very much both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error, because your `@user` is `nil`.

What I can see from your comments is you need to update this

```
before_action :set_user, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

to this

```
before_action :set_user, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :finish_signup]
```